# Learning to write a solitaire game

Tags: 2d, card-game, source-code

Many years ago I did some programming in TurboPascal (on DOS!), but have not programmed since. Since retiring, I have "invented" a few solitaire games that I have given to people who sell solitaire collections. Recently I've invented a game that is different enough from existing solitaires that it does not "fit" into these collection packages. I would have no difficulty writing a simple program to do the job in TP, but that is no longer an option. I purchased BlitzPlus, but would like some help getting started. I hate the idea of reinventing the wheel; ie, learning from scratch how to shuffle decks, assign graphic files to cards in the program, etc, so, ideally, I'd like some basic source code from a very basic (ie, nothing fancy required) solitaire program, but, if necessary, would start from just tutorials on some of the procedures likely to be required. As I said, I've already purchased BlitzPlus, but would be willing to use some other language if that would be better or offer more tutorial assistance. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, but you might want to rephrase your question - there is a rule of 'not asking how to make an entire game'. Maybe 'What resources exist for solitaire like games?'

Answer (score 2):

I've never coded a card-game but I feel like encouraging a beginning game programmer. So I just accumulated little bit of resources from the internet.

[This is a solitaire game in java](http://javasol.sourceforge.net/) and since I thought you might not be familiar with concepts like svn i am including [a link](http://javasol.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/javasol/trunk/javasol/src/com/fbergeron/) to the source code directory which you might find useful.The site above I mentioned uses the Java programming language.I think the only things you might need to do will be

1. Modifying the art assets in the above project
2. Changing the game-play to suit your ai.

Best Wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few links that might help. One is C++ and the other is in Visual Basic, but you may be able to glean something from them and get started. The C++ site is a project assignment from a college and is pretty much just an outline.
[Visual Basic](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=130837)
[C++](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/classes/cs3411b_99_winter/P1Final.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Actionscript 3.0 (flash) to build 2D card games. Here are a couple of tutorials:
1)http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/12/30/guessnext-complete-flash-game-with-highscores/
2)http://www.developphp.com/Flash_tutorials/show_tutorial.php?tid=221
3)you could check out: http://www.gotoandplay.it/ (it has a lot of tutorials)